# Integral $\int e^t\left(\sin^6{at} +\cos^4{at}\right)dt $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi} e^t\left(\sin^6{at} +\cos^4{at}\right)dt $$

$$\int e^t\left(1-2\sin^2{at}\cos^2{at} - \sin^4{at}\cos^2{at}\right) $$
$$\int e^t\left(1-\sin^2{at}\cos^2{at}\left(2 +\frac{1-\cos{2at}}{2}\right) \right)$$
$$ \int e^t -\frac58e^t\sin^2{2at} +\frac18 e^t\sin^2{2at}\cos{2at} $$
$$=e^{\pi}-1$$
It can be further solved by Integrating by part. But this is competition question so it is   becoming lengthy. Is there any other way to solve it quickly?

Comment: is the result of the indefinite integral?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry,Can't understand what you mean .

Comment: i the result given below the indefinite or the definite integral?

Comment: Result is in definite form .

Comment: i think your result is not true.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It's not the result ,I simplified it in that form.It is the integral in simplified form.

Comment: Judging from the long and nasty answer I suspect something is wrong if you are about to calculate that integral by hand in 2 to 2.5 minutes.

Comment: @mickep Similar integral is also there in paper ,so question overall time increases to 4 .Limit is just changed.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the trigonometric sum in the brackets can be simplified to $$\frac{1}{32} (\cos (2 a t)+10 \cos (4 a t)-\cos (6 a t)+22)$$